# Modifying the grunt-ngDocs template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, documentation, ngdoc

How can I modify the look&feel template of the website generated by [grunt-ngDocs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-ngdocs) ?

The final goal is to integrate the generated documentation inside a website.

Per example, we want to display the following tabs for each topic

- Demo (focused on the final user rendering)
- Code (for the developers)

To do that, we need to modify the template used by ngDocs, but how ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create different tabs just add another [Target](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-ngdocs#targets) to the ngdocs task:

```
ngdocs: {
  options: {        
    ...
    startPage: '/code' // this is displayed first
    ...        
  },
  demo: {
    src: ['path/to/demo/files'],
    title: 'Demo'
  },
  code: {
    src: ['path/to/code/files'],
    title: 'Code'
  }
}
```

Now, regarding the custom template.

You can provide your own [Template file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-ngdocs#template) and [CSS file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-ngdocs#styles).

You can even create a custom [Navigation Template](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-ngdocs#navtemplate)

Answer (score 0):

You may style the template provided with your own css files that you can copy each time you generate the docs.

See https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-ngdocs#styles? where you may specify styles in the option object used to intitialize your docs in grunt